# Switch between LoginView and MainView with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, clean-architecture

So I have a Application in which the user need to Login and then the MainView should start and the LoginView should Close. So how can i start from the LoginViewModel the MainView and close the LoginView

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by having a sort of "Master View" (as the Main Window), which would contain a `ContentControl` for its total content. This would first load the Login View, and then once the user is authenticated and authorized, would present the Main View.

For switching between the views, the approach I'd probably take would be to have an event on the Login ViewModel, something like `OnSuccessfulLogin`, which the "Master ViewModel" would listen for, then load the Main ViewModel as its content once it hears of a successful login. I'd probably also have some kind of custom `EventsArgs` class that passes an authenticated user `object` back to the Main ViewModel as part of the `OnSuccessfulLogin` event.